# Reclaiming Memory of Large Objects In Python - Windows and Ubuntu Differences

Tags: python, ubuntu, garbage-collection

When I run the following code on Ubuntu and watch in htop, it peaks out at 900 mb of memory usage until sleep() is done:

```
import random
import gc
import time

large_dict = {}
for x in xrange(50000):
    large_row = {}
    for y in xrange(125):
        large_row[random.randint(1, 10000000000)] = random.randint(1, 10000000000)
    large_dict[random.randint(1, 10000000000)] = large_row


# Force a sweep
large_dict = {}
del large_dict
gc.collect()

time.sleep(60)
```

However, when I run it on Windows and watch task manager, memory usage is only a few mb after gc.collect().

I tried this code in Ubuntu with Python 2.7.3, 2.7.4, and 2.7.8 with the same results.

Why are Windows and Ubuntu behaving differently? I would prefer Ubuntu to act like Windows and free the memory after gc.collect().

Answer (score 1):

> The fact that the free lists grow does not seem like much of a problem
>   because the memory it contains is still accessible to the Python
>   program. But from the OS’s perspective, your program’s size is the
>   total (maximum) memory allocated to Python. Since Python returns
>   memory to the OS on the heap (that allocates other objects than small
>   objects) **only on Windows**, if you run on Linux, you can only see the
>   total memory used by your program increase.

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html